# Generate route for Sushi Swap Route Processor processRoute contract method

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py, sushiswap

I'm trying to programically use RouteProcessor smart contract by Sushi Swap.
Here you can see contract https://etherscan.io/address/0xF70c086618dcf2b1A461311275e00D6B722ef914.
I gathered information about all parameters but could not find any description about how to determine route parameter.
So how do you generate route?

Thanks for any help.

This is a code that i try to run to swap ETH -> ARB in Arbitrum Nova chain.

```
from eth_abi import encode
from web3 import Web3

arbitrum_nova_rpc_url = 'https://nova.arbitrum.io/rpc'
wallet_address = '<your address here>'

route_processor_abi = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_bentoBox","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"bentoBox","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract IBentoBoxMinimal","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"route","type":"bytes"}],"name":"processRoute","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"transferValueTo","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountValueTransfer","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"route","type":"bytes"}],"name":"transferValueAndprocessRoute","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]'
route_processor_arbitrum_nova_address = '0xaB235da7f52d35fb4551AfBa11BFB56e18774A65'

# Generate route here
arbitrum_nova_ether_address = '0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE'
arbitrum_nova_weth_address = '0x722E8BdD2ce80A4422E880164f2079488e115365'
arbitrum_nova_arbitrum_address = '0xf823C3cD3CeBE0a1fA952ba88Dc9EEf8e0Bf46AD'

byte_ether_address = encode(['address'], [web3.to_checksum_address(arbitrum_nova_ether_address)])
byte_weth_address = encode(['address'], [web3.to_checksum_address(arbitrum_nova_weth_address)])
byte_arb_address = encode(['address'], [web3.to_checksum_address(arbitrum_nova_arbitrum_address)])

route = byte_ether_address + byte_weth_address + byte_arb_address

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(arbitrum_nova_rpc_url))

contract = web3.eth.contract(
    address=route_processor_arbitrum_nova_address, 
    abi=route_processor_abi
)

tx = contract.functions.processRoute(
    web3.to_checksum_address(arbitrum_nova_ether_address),  # token in
    web3.to_wei(0.0001, 'ether'),  # amount in
    web3.to_checksum_address(arbitrum_nova_arbitrum_address),  # token out
    0,  # amount out min
    web3.to_checksum_address(address),  # to address
    route # route
)

tx.build_transaction({
    "nonce": web3.eth.get_transaction_count(address),
    "value": 0
})
```

Comment: hey man , you figured it out ?

Answer (score 1):

Sushiswap cross-chain swap is plugging into Layer0’s [Stargate](https://stargate.finance/) bridge infrastructure. in this project input of the router's value is based on chainID.
I recommend reading [this doc](https://stargateprotocol.gitbook.io/stargate/developers/how-to-swap) for a better understanding.

[1 - what's Stargate](https://stargate.finance/)

[2 - sushiswap multichain swap article](https://www.sushi.com/blog/sushi-xswap-a-crosschain-dex)

[3 - starGate gitBook](https://stargateprotocol.gitbook.io/stargate/developers/how-to-swap)

Answer (score 0):

The `route` parameter should be a `bytes` value that encodes the path of the tokens to be swapped.

like if you want to swap Ether for `ARBITRUM`, and the path involves first converting `Ether` to `WETH` and then converting `WETH` to `ARBITRUM`, the `route` is like the example below

```
from eth_abi import encode_single

eth_address = web3.to_checksum_address(arbitrum_nova_ether_address)
weth_address = web3.to_checksum_address(arbitrum_nova_weth_address)
arb_address = web3.to_checksum_address(arbitrum_nova_arbitrum_address)

encoded_eth = encode_single('address', eth_address)
encoded_weth = encode_single('address', weth_address)
encoded_arb = encode_single('address', arb_address)
```

you just have to concatenate the encoded token `addresses` to form the `route` paramete: `route = encoded_eth + encoded_weth + encoded_arb` then pass this `route` parameter to the `processRoute()`

Comment: Hey, man. First of all thanks for help. I did as you said in your comment, just used another method in `eth_abi` cause there is no one in new version of library. I still get transaction reverted error. I updated my example with real arbitrum nova data. Can you spot what i did wrong?

Comment: I modified my answer